# GUI tool for Windows computers to administer SAMBA

Tags: gratis, windows-7, samba

I have a few **SAMBA v3** servers on my network that I constantly need to remote into with SSH to change settings. I know that for SAMBA v4 (which we are **not** upgrading to for a while), you can use the Windows Server Remote Administration Tools to administer it, but you can't for SAMBA v3.

What I need is:

- GUI based application
- Secure Tunnel connection to the server (i.e. over SSH)
- Free (as in beer)
- Works from Windows 7 Professional x64

What would be nice:

- Tree hierarchy for folders
- Permissions
- Group/user editing

The servers are running Debian Wheezy (version 7.1), but I figured SAMBA is open enough that it can run on any Linux flavour.